# ImportError: cannot import name HTMLParser

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am new to python, I am getting following error :

```
C:\infinidat_aptare>pip install --upgrade infi.projector infi.recipe.application_package    
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main  
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)  
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code  
    exec code in run_globals  
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 42, in   <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 16, in <module>  
    from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import unescape  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.py", line 45, in <module>  
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser  
ImportError: cannot import name HTMLParser
```

---

```
C:\>pip --version   
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main  
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)  
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code  
    exec code in run_globals  
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>  
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>  
    from pip._internal.index import (  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 16, in <module>  
    from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import unescape  
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.py", line 45, in <module>  
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser  
ImportError: cannot import name HTMLParser
```

---

I even tried importing it from python shell :

```
C:\>python  
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
 from HTMLParser import HTMLParser  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ImportError: cannot import name HTMLParser
```

The only  change that I made was installing "pip install pythonwpy" on our windows machine before which everything was working fine.

Please do help me on the same.

OS version : Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Python version : 2.7.8

Comment: Verify there is a file `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\HTMLParser.py`. Looks like it's missing, so you need to reinstall Python. And if you need to reinstall Python anyway I recommend to install later version — at least 2.7.9, better 2.7.15. Earlier versions have SSL-related problems with `pip` and PyPI.

Comment: I  have uninstalled 2.7.9 and installed 2.7.15 but could not verify whether HTMLParser.py was missing in that location. Anyways after installing 2.7.15 I am not seeing the issue.